# changing specialisations afterwards

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

Is it possible to change your class after you chose one?
Like you played rift mage a while but now want to be a knight enchanter? 
I know there is no dual specialisation like before but is it possible to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can cannot change your specialization once the appropriate quest has been completed.